# $2$-norm of matrix absolute norm

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

> A matrix norm for which $\lvert \lvert A \rvert \rvert = \lvert \lvert \ \lvert A \rvert  \ \rvert \rvert$ is called an absolute norm, having denoted by $\lvert A \rvert$ the matrix of absolute value of the entries of $A$. Prove that $\lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert\rvert_{2}$ is not an absolute norm.

#### Attempt at solution

**[Definition]** $$\lvert \lvert A \rvert\rvert_{2}  = \max\limits_{i = 1,\dots,n} \sigma_{i}(A),$$ where $\sigma_{i}$ represent the singular values of $A$, that is the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^T A$.

**[Definition]**
$$ \lvert \lvert A \rvert \rvert_{2} = \max\limits_{\lvert\lvert x \rvert \rvert_{2}=1} \lvert \lvert Ax \rvert \rvert_{2}.$$
**[Lemma]**

If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, then the eigenvalues of $A^T A$ are non-negative.

---

I suppose one could find a counter example, but that looks computationally heavy and I was not able to think of one.

\begin{gather*}
\langle(A^T A)u , u \rangle = \lambda \lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2} \implies \lambda = \frac
{\langle(A^T A)u , u \rangle}{\lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2}} = \frac{\lvert \lvert A u \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2} }{\lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2}}.
\end{gather*}
Let us consider $A^T A$ and $\lvert A\rvert^T \lvert A \rvert$. Suppose they share the same eigenvector $u$, then they should share the same eigenvalue. Then,
$$  \lambda_{1} = \frac{\lvert \lvert A u \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2} }{\lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2}}  , \qquad, \lambda_{2} = \frac{\lvert \lvert \ \lvert A \rvert \  u \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2} }{\lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2}},
$$
for $\lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2}$ , $Au$ must be equal to $\lvert A \rvert u$ which is not always the case. Thus,
$$ \lvert \lvert \ \lvert A \rvert \ \rvert \rvert_{2} = \max\limits_{i = 1,\dots,n} \sigma_{i} (\lvert A \rvert ) \neq \max\limits_{i = 1,\dots,n} \sigma_{i} (A).$$

---

I don't think my solution is correct. Anyone can confirm or has any clue on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: how about consider $3\times 3$ matrices that are symmetric and have mixed signs on them, then construct an example... sticking with $+1$ and $-1$ for components should be enough... e.g. $A:=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 &-1 \\ -1 & 1 &-1 \\ -1 &-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$